# Can I drink Dogfish Head Sixty One four years after the expiry date?

Tags: health, craft-beers

Can I drink Dogfish Head Sixty One four years after the expiry date?

Would there be any danger to one’s health? Will it just give a bad taste or is it harmful?

Comment: I don know that's why I am asking,it just will give a bad test or it is harmful?

Comment: You should send it to me, i will take the risk for you.

Answer (score 2):

There should be no danger to your health, it just probably won't taste very good depending on how well it's sealed.  61 is 6+% ABV which should be more than enough to prevent most if not all harmful pathogens from growing.  It's also absurdly hoppy which increased the antimicrobial properties even more.

If there's anything fuzzy or slimy floating around you may want to avoid it since the experience may be unpleasant but there shouldn't be anything in there that will actually make you sick.  There's a very specific reason alcoholic beverages in general are given a lot of credit for allowing human civilization to survive until we figured out germ theory and sanitary practices, and that's that alcoholic drinks became much safer than ground water after we invented the city.